# Display Django values() on Foreign Key in template as object instead of its id

Tags: django, django-templates, django-aggregation

I have a queryset in Django that calls `Model.objects.values('item')`... where `'item'` is a Foreign Key.

```
class Words(models.Model):
  word = models.CharField()

class Frequency(models.Model):
  word = models.ForeignKey(Words)
  ...
```

So this returns the item id and displays as an id in the template. How do I show the actual item value in the template instead of the id?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To refer properties of Foreign Key items, you should use '__' lookup notation in fields. `MyModel.objects.values('item__prop1', 'item__prop2', ...)` should work for you.

And you can print it in templates by referencing the property names like this, when the name of template variable for the result is `values`.

```
{% for v in values %}
    Prop1: {{ v.item__prop1 }}
    Prop2: {{ v.item__prop2 }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Obviously Achimnoi was using 'prop1' as an example - you should do `Model.objects.values('word__word')` in the view and `{{ v.word__word }}` in the template.

Comment: This seems a viable solution when you have a single model. However, in my case I have a list of models and each model has a list of FKs (actually a many-to-many relationship). But it seems that should not be a problem as the values are still FKs (point to IDs in another table). The view is also serializing the list of models to JSON.