# django templatetags not return correct data

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I've built a small templatetag that looks towards my DB and makes a calculation based on the most popular trophies logged.

**templatetag looks as follows:**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('trophies/trophies.html')
def trophies():
    return { 'trophies': Trophies.objects.values("specie").annotate(Count("id")).order_by()}
```

**trophies/trophies.html**

```
{% for obj in trophies %}
    <li><a href="/trophy-room/browse/?specie={{ obj.specie }}">{{ obj.specie }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**trophy model**

```
class Trophies(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    specie = models.ForeignKey(Specie)
```

**Specie model**

```
class Specie(ImageModel):
    species = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Common Name')
```

running `{{ obj.specie }}` returns the id, and running `{{ obj.specie.species }}` returns nothing.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('trophies/trophies.html')
def trophies():
    return { 'trophies': Trophies.objects.values("specie", "specie__species").annotate(Count("id")).order_by()}
```

And in template:

```
{{ obj.specie__species }}
```

See related question: [Display Django values() on Foreign Key in template as object instead of its id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602557/display-django-values-on-foreign-key-in-template-as-object-instead-of-its-id)